# My consumer receives every second message

Tags: python, rabbitmq

I'm trying to implement a simple producer and consumer architecture in my application. My base class for all producers is very simple

```
class ProducerBase(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    QUEUE: str = "default"
    EVENT: str

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.channel = None
        self.message = None

        self.logger = logging.getLogger()

    def produce(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._get_channel()

        self.prepare_message(*args, **kwargs)
        self.update_message()

        self.logger.info(f"Message: {self.message}")

        self.channel.basic_publish(exchange="", routing_key=self.QUEUE, body=json.dumps(self.message))

        self.logger.info(f"Message produced to queue: {self.QUEUE}")

    def _get_channel(self) -> None:
        connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.URLParameters(BROKER_URL))
        self.channel = connection.channel()

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def prepare_message(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        raise NotImplementedError

    def update_message(self) -> None:
        self.message.update({"event": self.EVENT})
```

I have not noticed any bugs, etc. When I need any instance to produce an event it does it perfectly.

Below you can see my base class for consumers.

```
class ConsumerBase:
    QUEUE: str = "default"
    HANDLERS: list = []
    DB_INITIALIZED: bool = False

    def __init__(self, db_required: bool = False) -> None:
        self.logger = logging.getLogger()
        self.db_required = db_required

    async def consume(self):
        if self.db_required and self.DB_INITIALIZED is False:
            self.logger.info("Connection to the database is being initialized")
            await self._set_db()

        connection = await aio_pika.connect_robust(BROKER_URL)

        self.logger.info(f"Waiting for messages from queue: {self.QUEUE}")

        async with connection:
            channel = await connection.channel()
            queue = await channel.declare_queue(self.QUEUE, durable=True)

            async with queue.iterator() as messages:
                async for message in messages:
                    await self.callback(message=message)

    @classmethod
    async def _set_db(cls):
        database_config = {
            "connections": {"default": DB_URL},
            "apps": {
                "models": {
                    "models": MODELS,
                    "default_connection": "default",
                },
            },
        }
        await Tortoise.init(config=database_config)
        await Tortoise.generate_schemas()
        cls.DB_INITIALIZED = True

    async def callback(self, message: Coroutine[any, any, AbstractIncomingMessage]):
        async with message.process():
            body = message.body.decode()
            data = json.loads(body)

            self.logger.info(f"Received message from queue: {self.QUEUE}")
            self.logger.info(f"Body: {data}")

            for handler in self.HANDLERS:
                await handler(message=data).handle()

    @classmethod
    def run_consumer(cls, db_required=False):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        consumer_instance = cls(db_required=db_required)
        loop.run_until_complete(consumer_instance.consume())
```

It works, however only every second time. What am I doing wrong? The consumer is in a separate Docker container. All the connections seems to be alright. If you need any additional files, configuration just let me know.

P. S.
I'm using Python 3.11 with FastAPI, TortoiseORM and postgreSQL.

Comment: Do you have two consumer instances running? That could explain why the one you're looking at is only getting every other request.

Comment: @JohanWalles, no. Only one consumer is listening on this queue.

Comment: @JohanWalles, in fact I did have something on that queue! A celery worker. Does it mean that I need to have one queue per pair (producer-consumer)?

Comment: Yes, one message on a queue can only be consumed/acknowledged per one consumer. Multiple consumers on the same queue will concurrently take messages from one another. Your use case probably requires an exchange and not a simple queue.